# R: Keep the first and last two rows of the dataframe and meanwhile deleting one rows of other middle dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a very specific question about data cleaning in R and am not sure how should I achieve this. Basically, you can find below an example data frame.

```
test <- data.frame(personID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                   sequenceTrip = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), departureHour = c(9L, 
                                                                               9L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 16L, 16L), departureMinute = c(34L, 
                                                                                                                                      34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 19L, 19L), tripRangeTypeOrigin = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), arrivalHour = c(10, 10, 14, 14, 15, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        15, 18, 18), arrivalMinute = c(34, 34, 34, 34, 49, 49, 4, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       4), tripRangeTypeDestin = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), tripPurpose = c("leisure", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "leisure", "return home", "return home", "shopping", "shopping", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "return home", "return home"), mode = c("car", "car", "car", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "car", "car", "car", "car", "car"), tripDistance = c(77, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         77, 77, 77, 100, 100, 115, 115), typicalDurationNextActivity = c(10800, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          10800, 60, 60, 1800, 1800, 24960, 24960), arrivalTimeInMInute = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1084, 1084), originDestinType = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), tripNB = c("MUTSAARD", "Outside Brussels", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Outside Brussels", "HEYSEL", "HEYSEL", "Outside Brussels", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Outside Brussels", "CHAUSSEE DE WAVRE - SAINT-JULIEN "))
```

What I want to achieve is keeping the 1st, 2nd, second last (row 7 in this case) and last (row 8 in this case) rows of this dataframe, meanwhile, for rows `3：6`, I want to filter out the rows which `originDestinType == 1`. So the final data frame would be 6 rows in total. I know this can be achieved by command like `rbind`, however, I am wondering if there is an easier way for achieving this using package like `dplyr`?

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This should be good :

```
df <- test %>% filter(rownames(test) %in% c(1,2,7,8) | originDestinType!=1)
```

Comment: instead of 7 and 8 you can use `nrow(test)-1` and `nrow(test)` in case you have a varying number of rows

Comment: thats true, but i didnt know if he wanted his example reproducible on a bigger database or just on this one. Because it seemed really precise

Comment: Hi Wietse, sorry for my lack of interpretation. I did want to make it on a bigger database with un-defined number of row :)

Comment: Hi BPeif, I think this code is not working when combined with group_by function

Answer (score 0):

Update after clarification: Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
  groub_by(yourgroup) %>%
  filter(row_number() == first(row_number(),2) |
           row_number() == last(row_number(),2) |
             originDestinType == 1)
```

1. List item

Here is a `dplyr` solution:
We could use `filter` with `|` and `&` operator and `first` and `last` function:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
  filter(row_number() == first(row_number(),2) |
           row_number() == last(row_number(),2) |
           row_number() %in% (3:6) & originDestinType == 1)
```

output:

```
  originDestinType                            tripNB
1                0                          MUTSAARD
2                1                  Outside Brussels
3                1                            HEYSEL
4                1                  Outside Brussels
5                0                  Outside Brussels
6                1 CHAUSSEE DE WAVRE - SAINT-JULIEN
```

Comment: Hi TarJae, the problem is this is an example data, and in my real project, we have an undefined number of rows within different groups. So 'row_number() %in% (3:6)' may not work with all group. Just wondering if you have better idea to replace this :) Thanks

Comment: This should be easy: We could use `test %>% group_by(xyz) %>% filter(... `

Comment: Hi TarJae, I know the `group_by` function, what I mean is some groups will have 10 rows, some will have 12 rows for example. But I still want to keep the first, second, second last and last row and meanwhile filtering the row that `originDestinType == 1`. Hope this is better for clarification :) Thanks

Comment: Please see my update!

Comment: Hi Tarjae, I get the following error, do you know the reason for this? Or I will produce another example code with two groups
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
i Input `..1` is `|...`.
x subscript out of bounds
i The error occurred in group 1: personID = 1

Comment: And I find the updated code will produce the same error with my original example if add `group_by(personID)`